# Dell Precision 7520 GPU fan going ON OFF ON OFF

Tags: windows-10, laptop, gpu, fan, dell-precision

My dell 7520 (out of warranty), 3 months ago I started getting this weird on off pattern for my GPU fan.

One dude helped me, temporarily, now it started again after 1 month!

is buying a new fans gonna fix this?

ALWAYS when i turn it on it says "fan malfunction"

It is so bad now, every time I boot it, it happens. I restart, download all available drivers, STILL NOTHING

what is going on???

I searched it and I found that I have to update the bios, I did, next thing was to clean the fans, didn't worked as well. The on off stopped for 1 month, I though I fixed, but then again it started I found a way to fix it by stopping the fan and running it again, but it only works temporarily

Temps:

CPU-80C

GPU-70C   at max load

specs:

i7-7820HQ

Quadro M2200

32GB RAM

NVMe SSD boot device & SSD

Comment: Yes; You should replace the fan

Comment: damn it i guess, they are expensive

Comment: A computer repair store can replace just the G

Answer (score 0):

Try Opening it and use a Blower on it. Dust Sometimes makes the fan run faster due to more heat which is made due to dust collecton.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with my Dell 7520 out of the box. Dell ended up replacing a bunch of parts with no success. Fans, cpu ect. The on/off/on pulsing of the fan was driving me crazy. I ended up finding the solution online. To fix this do the following. FYI, if you update the bios in the future you will need to do this again.

- Open the Control Panel
- Open Hardware and Sound
- Open Power Options
- Select Balanced (recommended)
- Select Change plan Settings
- Select Change advanced power settings
- Select Processor power management
- Select System cooling policy
- Change On battery: Passive
- Change Plugged in: Passive
- Select OK
- Go to Dell Command Power Manager
- Select Thermal Management
- Select Optimized as the Thermal Setting.
- Restart your computer